# Find the determinant of this $n\times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
-n & 1 & \cdots & 1  \\
1 & -n & \cdots & 1  \\
\vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & -n \end{array}\right)$$

Is a matrix with $-n$ full diagonal and the other part of matrix are $1$, i think that the answer is $-(n-1)^{n-1}$, because this is the sequence if we replace $n$ by $1,2,3,4,\cdots$, but i want find more elegant demonstration, i don't now how to find determinant with laplace theorem of $n\times n$ matrix

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that the determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues (*repeated based on their algebraic multiplicity*)?  Letting $1_{n\times n}$ be the $n\times n$ matrix consisting entirely of ones, note your matrix is $1_{n\times n} - (n+1)I_{n\times n}$.  Can you find the eigenvalues of this with that in mind?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Here it is a different approach for the sake of curiosity:

\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
-n & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1\\
1 & -n & 1 & \ldots & 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & -n
\end{vmatrix} & =
\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1\\
-1 & -n & 1 & \ldots & 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
-1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & -n
\end{vmatrix}\\\\
& =
\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
-1 & -n-1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -n - 1
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}

Now you can develop the determinant along the first row. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ohhh thanks ,ok i understand the matrix transformation, now the determinant will be the product of the principal diagonal, because already we made the triangular triangulation, right?, i thing is $-(-n-1)^{n-1}$

Comment: That's the idea!

Answer (score 1):

Denote the matrix by $A$.

Then $dim(nullspace(A+(n+1)I))=n-1 $
And , as sum of each row is $(-1)$

So, $-(n+1)$ is the eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $n-1$

And $(-1)$ is the another eigenvalue with multiplicity $1$

So, $det(A)=(-1)^{n} (n+1)^{n-1}$